# Upgrading Gatsby v4 to v5

Tags: npm, node-modules

I am using an Apple M1 Max processor and using MAC os Ventura 13.0.

I am on Node v18.12.1 (npm v8.19.2)

After using the

```
gatsby new
```

and setting up the site, it's installed to Gatsby 4, and React to 18.1.0 and after running this command:

```
npm install gatsby@next --legacy-peers-deps
```

I see that in my package.json file that Gatsby is now set to: 5.0.0-next.16.

Then running the command:

```
nvm install 18
```

I then run the command:

```
npm run develop
```

but then I run into the following error:

> Missing onError handler for invocation 'building-schema', error was
> 'Error: Cannot create as TypeComposer the following value:
> GraphQLScalarType({ name: "Date", description: "A date string, such as
> 2007-12-03, compliant with  the ISO 8601 standard for representation
> of dates and times using the Gregorian calendar.", specifiedByURL:
> undefined, serialize: [function String], parseValue: [function
> String], parseLiteral: [function parseLiteral], extensions: {  },
> astNode: undefined, extensionASTNodes: [] }).'. Stacktrace was 'Error:
> Cannot create as TypeComposer the following value:
> GraphQLScalarType({ name: "Date", description: "A date string, such as
> 2007-12-03, compliant with  the ISO 8601 standard for representation
> of dates and times using the Gregorian calendar.", specifiedByURL:
> undefined, serialize: [function String], parseValue: [function
> String], parseLiteral: [function parseLiteral], extensions: {  },
> astNode: undefined, extensionASTNodes: [] }).

Is this an Apple silicon issue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, after I deleted the `package-lock.json` file and deleted the `node_modules` folder, I ran `gatsby develop` and this ran.

I have not figured out what the previous issue was, but it's working now.

Comment: I've got the same issue and exactly the same error message. But unfortunately your solution didn't work for me. Any further ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the multiple version of `graphql` installation. You need to add `resolutions` property to your `package.json` file for installing only one version of `graphql`.

```js
  "resolutions": {
    "graphql": "16.0.0"
  }
```

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v4-to-v5/#multiple-versions-of-graphql

Answer (score 0):

Multiple versions of either `graphql` or `gatsby` installed, especially for that kind of `monorepo` type projects.